# PHP preg_replace with keeping the match not working

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a simple function to search for a word in a string and link it. The problem is that sometimes the word has a dot or comma at the end of it, and I would like to preserve it. so `text word.` should change to `text <a href="#">word</a>.` and not to `text <a href="#">word</a>`

this is my function up to now. I don't understand why it isn't working:

```
$string = "words are plenty in the world. another world and another world,comma.";

function findWord ($string, $word, $link) {
    $patt = "/(?:^|[^a-zA-Z])(" . preg_quote($word, '/') . ")(?:$|[^a-zA-Z])/i";
    return preg_replace($patt, ' <a href="'.$link.'" class="glossary-item">'.$word.'</a>$3', $string);
}

echo findWord ($string, "world", "#");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used non-capturing groups `(?:...)` to match the characters that possibly surround your search word, but then use `$3` as if they were capturing groups `(...)`.

Therefore, `$3` will always be empty. You could either use capturing groups instead:

```
function findWord ($string, $word, $link) {
    $patt = "/(^|[^a-zA-Z])(" . preg_quote($word, '/') . ")($|[^a-zA-Z])/i";
    return preg_replace($patt, '$1<a href="'.$link.'" class="glossary-item">'.$word.'</a>$3', $string);
}
```

(but then don't forget to also replace `$1` in your string!) or use [negative lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
function findWord ($string, $word, $link) {
    $patt = "/(?<![a-zA-Z])(" . preg_quote($word, '/') . ")(?![a-zA-Z])/i";
    return preg_replace($patt, '<a href="'.$link.'" class="glossary-item">'.$word.'</a>', $string);
}
```

I'd prefer the latter.

Comment: Just one question. Could this (word boundaries modifier) be used too, in this case:  return preg_replace("%\b$word\b%i", ' <a href="'.$link.'" class="glossary-item">'.$word.'</a>', $string); ?

Comment: @nevermind: Yes, but it would work differently. For example, the current regex would extract `abc` from `_abc1` which a regex with word boundaries wouldn't.